# Call Request Header Cookie

Tags: ruby, http, cookies

I'm working on an application which i took over from someone else. I am trying to get a routerid behind a load balancer and have noticed the previous guy was able to set this in the Cookie Request Header. I want to be able to call this information and display it to see what server is providing a page.

```
Cookie:ROUTEID=.1; blah blah blah
```

I have tried;

```
request.headers["Cookie"]
```

and a few variations thereof but cant seem to get the information.

```
response['Cache-Control']
```

This returns data but for some reason request.headers will not. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: What i want to retrieve]

Comment: Which http gem are you using?

Comment: @jmccure have require 'socket', require 'net/http', require 'uri' and require "cgi" at top of document though i have no specific gem in gemfile. Do i need one? I thought the require would suffice but am a novice so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I would need to see the actual code, but try `response.get_fields('set-cookie')`

Comment: @jmccure Apologies if i'm mistaken but i'm looking for the Cookie in request headers not the set-cookie in response headers. Does that make less or more sense and is this achievable.

Comment: I see. In that case, I think it would be: `request['Cookie']` or request.getfields('Cookie') or `request.header.each_header {|key,value| puts "#{key} = #{value}" }` as per http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPHeader.html